# SQL - Get highest utilization by member by provider

Tags: sql, excel, vba, select

My data looks something like this:

```
Member - Provider - UtilizationCounts

123    - AA       - 10
234    - BB       - 8
456    - AA       - 7
123    - CC       - 5
```

I need to show member info and provider info that had the highest utilization.  So the results should look something like:

```
Member - Provider - UtilizationCounts

123    - AA       - 10
234    - BB       - 8
456    - AA       - 7
```

Comment: Do you always need just 3 results?, or are we missing something from your example?

Comment: I think below answers not correct. I guess TC meant that he needs to find All highest providers for each member. so, If 234 has 3 BBB with values 10,20,30 the query should return 234-BBB-30

Comment: @user194076 - If so, he hasn't make it clear. Maybe adding more results to the example can help you get a better answer

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear enough.  I have a couple of thousand records like this.  I checked the results by creating a pivot on provider volume by member sorted by the utilization.  Taking about 10 random members, I was able to test that the below answer worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you're wanting is to have one row for each member, and then the provider and utilization count corresponding to the highest utilization count.

It seems like this should work.  Let me know.

```
SELECT *
FROM Member
WHERE Member.UtilizationCounts = 
          (SELECT MAX(UtilizationCounts) 
           FROM Member m2 
           WHERE m2.MemberID = Member.MemberID)
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle, you need to use a native column named `rownum` like this:

```
SELECT Member, Provider, UtilizationCounts
FROM (
    SELECT rownum, Member, Provider, UtilizationCounts
    FROM myData
    ORDER BY UtilizationCounts DESC
)
WHERE rownum <= 3
```

See this documentation: [ROWNUM Pseudocolumn](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm)

Comment: I'm working on Oracle 9.2, Is there another way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
select Member, Provider, UtilizationCounts
from YourTable
order by UtilizationCounts desc
```

This will bring everything, ordered from highest to lowest. I'm not sure if you want to filter something out. If you only want the TOP 3, assuming you are using SQL Server, you'd go with:

```
select TOP 3 Member, Provider, UtilizationCounts
from YourTable
order by UtilizationCounts desc
```